# JavaScript data into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, templates, hiccup

I'm looking for a particular JS library that turns hiccup-like data such as

```
['a', { href: 'https://example.com' }, 'Example']
```

into the corresponding HTML string:

```
'<a href="https://example.com">Example</a>'
```

IIRC, this library is quite popular (should have thousands of stars on GitHub), but I can't for the life of me remember its name, and I tried searching for it in several different ways.

EDIT: While searching, I found [this library](https://github.com/armikhalev/hilang), which seems to have the same functionality, but it's not the one I'm looking for.

EDIT 2: Yishmeray's comment reminded me that the library I'm looking for does more than just creating that string - I *think* it creates a DOM from the array, registers and de-registers event handlers, compares diffs to update affected parts of the DOM, etc.

PS: At first I wasn't sure if this is the kind of question one should post on SO, but according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632), I'm guessing it is, as my question is about a "software [tool] commonly used by programmers."

Comment: Isn't this is it? https://github.com/Jxck/html2json

Comment: Of course you can use whatever library you like, but that sure looks to me like an exceedingly small amount of code to just plain write!

Comment: @MattDavis No, I don't think that's it.

Comment: @Yishmeray, IIRC the library does more stuff, like turning your array into an HTML DOM, registering and de-registering handlers, etc.